# How to use regex and negation with a class inside if else

Tags: regex, bash

I want to check if a variable passes the regex `[a-z\-]+`, what I tried was

```
NAME_A="something"
NAME_B="Something_Wrong"
VALID_CHARACTERS="[a-z\-]+"

if [[ ! $NAME_A =~ $VALID_CHARACTERS ]]; then
    echo "NAME_A failed";
    exit 1
else 
    echo "NAME_A passed"
fi

if [[ ! $NAME_B =~ $VALID_CHARACTERS ]]; then
    echo "NAME_B failed";
    exit 1
else 
    echo "NAME_B passed"
fi
```

but the if conditions are always true.
([online bash fiddle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQ1AxcTVlUmlSak0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the start (`^`) and end anchor (`$`), to indicate the start and end of the pattern to match respectively. Without these, the regex pattern  `[a-z\-]+` would always return a match for the given inputs as there is at least one lowercase alphabetic character in both input strings.

So, make the pattern as:

```
VALID_CHARACTERS="^[a-z\-]+$"
```

[Demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQ1AxcTVlUmlSak0)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong regex. Change it to "^[a-z]+" and it will work.

```
NAME_A="something"
NAME_B="Something_Wrong"
VALID_CHARACTERS="^[a-z]+"

if [[ ! $NAME_A =~ $VALID_CHARACTERS ]]; then
    echo "NAME_A failed";
    exit 1
else 
    echo "NAME_A passed"
fi

if [[ ! $NAME_B =~ $VALID_CHARACTERS ]]; then
    echo "NAME_B failed";
    exit 1
else 
    echo "NAME_B passed"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also go with what your question asked and that is negation of the regex:

```
NAME_A="something"
NAME_B="Something_Wrong"
VALID_CHARACTERS="[^a-z-]"

if [[ $NAME_A =~ $VALID_CHARACTERS ]]; then
    echo "NAME_A failed";
    exit 1
else
    echo "NAME_A passed"
fi

if [[ $NAME_B =~ $VALID_CHARACTERS ]]; then
    echo "NAME_B failed";
    exit 1
else
    echo "NAME_B passed"
fi
```

Comment: Using `^` inside `[]` is negation and I wan't to accept those characters. Thanks for checking this anyway.

Comment: You seemed to have missed the point, by negating the regex you are saying you are only accepting those characters.  So if the string contains any characters no in brackets then it is a failure.  Did you try the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid regex by using extended glob condition as this:

```
shopt -s extglob
isvalid() { [[ $1 == +([a-z-]) ]]; }
```

Then test it as:

```
isvalid "something-valid" && echo "ok" || echo "no"
ok

isvalid "something" && echo "ok" || echo "no"
ok


isvalid "something_wrong" && echo "ok" || echo "no"
no
```